# make, gcc and other developer tools unavailable after installing XCode on Lion

Tags: macos, development

I installed XCode after I upgraded to OS X Lion, I downloaded XCode from the App Store. `gcc`, `make` and such are still not found and I cannot compile anything from source because of this. I did a `find / -name make` and it looks like it found something:

```
/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates/Framework & Library/JNI Library/make
/Developer/usr/bin/make
```

What's going on here? Is this normal?

Comment: This is usually a bug in Xcode 4.1 only - especially for people with custom shells. Have you verified this still happens after running the latest Xcode 4.1.1?

Answer (score 7):

Is `/Developer/usr/bin` in your PATH variable?

You could try `ln -s /Developer/usr/bin/make /usr/bin/make`

Comment: Damn, beat me by seconds. Upvoted for speed! lol

Comment: @Bryson Woo! Score!

Comment: i just had my WTF!? moment, too. thanks for clarifying things ...

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your system's `$PATH` has been updated. If you had a terminal window open before you installed, and are using the same one now that you have Xcode installed, open a new one and let it run through .bashrc/.bash_profile/etc again to update the path. If you know the specific file that the $PATH variable lives in on your system, you can also just run `source` on that file.

If that doesn't work, you can manually add the path that the `find` command finds these tools at (should be `/Developer/usr/bin`) to your `$PATH` inside `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (depending on how your bash files are configured — mine has everything in `~/.bashrc` but I've customized them heavily).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, looks like Apple has moved all the Developer Tools under /Developer. Why, beats me. Fixing the $PATH is easy, but the annoying part is that the includes have also moved under /Developer/usr/include etc.

I spent a good half a day trying to compile some PHP extensions, to no avail, running into all sorts of "blah.h not found" errors.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out. They're under /Developer because installing Xcode from App Store does not install Xcode, but an app named "Install Xcode". After running it, everything went back to normal. :)